# Android TTS Male Female Voice Change

Tags: android, voice, text-to-speech

I am working with TTS.

But i need to change the voice of the tts from female to male and vice versa.

I know i can do it by eSpeak. But problem is that. In the setting page when i select the eSpeak TTS the voice changes to male and when i choose the Pico TTS the voice turns to female.
But when after changing the engine in the setting page when i try to change the voice and try to use that changed voice in my app it only speaks in male voice.

I download the third party app from http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tts/

Then in my app's MainActivity i do the below,

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    Button speak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakButton);
    speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, ConfigurationManager.class));
            else {
                tts = new TTS(Main.this, ttsInitListener, true );
            }

        }

    });
```

But what i am trying to do is without entering to the TextToSpeech Setting page, only changing a male/female button i want to change the voice for TTS.

[image]

Please help me to do so. I have tried lots of times.

Comment: HI Debarati, I am also try same sdk but not work properly, Pls Can you help me, Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can not switch from the default female voice on the android TTS you will need to use another engine. iSpeech and Nuance have really good engines and support male and female voices.